# SharePoint App Subsite MIME Issue

Tags: sharepoint-addin, css

I have a 2013 App / Add-in deployed in two places. The parent site app deploy  looks good and inherits the Master Page and CSS.

```
http://app-98619708df59c5.testapps.com/sites/testapp/AppURL/Pages/Default.aspx
```

But when I deploy that same app to a Subsite,

```
http://app-98619708df59c5.testapps.com/sites/testapp/AppURL/subsite//Pages/Default.aspx
```

..no CSS is loaded and the console throws the error:

```
**SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch**
```

Any ideas on what's happening?

Comment: Did you try in multiple browsers?For troubleshooting  try in chrome if you haven't done yet

Comment: same issue in Chrome, similar error "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:"

Comment: maybe use fiddler or chrome's network tracing feature to check the http request/response for the css file?

Answer (score 0):

What's the CSS URL? If it's relative, the subsite might be trying to hit an invalid URL, causing an error and thus the browser is unable to interpret the response into a valid CSS file.

Check the http traffic with the Network tab or a tool like Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

From [this thread at Technet Forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0e8bc22-827a-4596-8d5e-4719a5079fee/solvedforms-not-rendering-in-new-environment-with-ie?forum=sharepointadmin):

> The URL of the server's domain contained an underscore ex :
>   (http://cont_oso/) by changing it to a hypen ex : (http://cont-oso/)
>   the problem was solved ! (also needed to change the name in the
>   bindings)

If your subsite has any non-alphanumeric chars in URL, it might be useful to check.

Comment: Also, I wonder if double slash in question was a typo?
> `subsite//Pages`

Comment: the double slash was a typo ha. But there are no underscores or alphanumeric characters in the URL

Comment: Ok, guess I'll leave this answer for future googlers. Did you have a chance to setup Fiddler and see the MIME code in actual response for css file?

Comment: App.css in Fiddler is getting a 304 Result. But I'm unsure where to look for MIME within a response

Comment: Like http://i.imgur.com/vrplxvM.png. Does it give 304 even when app is deployed to root? Also, could you clear browser cache and test both cases?

Comment: `HTTP 304` does not have a body, so if there is any `Content Type` in response, it's meaningless. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691318/what-headers-do-i-want-to-send-together-with-a-304-response. Now lets find out what HTTP response code is sent from root, and you'll have a good hypothesis to start debugging